# Empty set in an algebra or sigma-algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

Does an algebra (or a sigma-algebra) contains the empty set or a set containing the empty set?

E.g., let $X$ be a set. Is the trivial sigma-algebra $\{\emptyset,X\}$ or $\{\{\emptyset\},\{X\}\}$?

Comment: A sigma algebra contains *subsets* of $X$. $\emptyset$ and $X$ are always subsets of $X$, while $\{\emptyset\}$ and $\{X\}$ are not!

Answer (score 3):

The usual definition of $\sigma$-algebra states that it contains the empty set.

An algebra of sets is closed under intersection and complement, so if it contains $A$ it contains $A \cap A^c = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your answer. In understand what you are saying. However, my question was rather, shall we write $\{\{\emptyset\},\{A\},\{A^c\},\{X\}\}$ or $\{\emptyset,\{A\},\{A^c\},X\}$?

Comment: An algebra or $\sigma$-algebra is a collection of subsets of $X$.  So $\{\emptyset, A, A^c, X\}$.