# Why is $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}$ in the definition of an algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In the definition of a  an algebra the first condition is $\Omega\in\mathcal{A}$. However does not this follow from the condition of complementation and intersection of finite collection is  closed . I mean if $A\in\mathcal{A}$ be any set, then $A\cap A^{c}=\varnothing$ is in $\mathcal{A}$. And since $\varnothing^{c}=\Omega$ then $\Omega\in\mathcal{A}$ . I get that if we are in a sigma algebra, then to go to the notion of finite intersection from countable intersection, we need $\Omega$ or $\phi$ to be there . But what is the need for it in an algebra?

I am refering to the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) definition here.

This answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841230/empty-set-in-an-algebra-or-sigma-algebra) states a similar thing.

So my question is: Why is the following definition of an algebra not sufficient

An algebra is a collection of subsets of a given set $\Omega$ such that it is closed under complementation and finite intersections/finite unions?

Comment: It is sufficient but you should say **non-empty** collection.

Comment: This is to assure the algebra is non-empty. And indeed by your reasoning, as soon as an algebra is non-empty, it has to contain both the empty set and the entire set itself. Therefore, this introduces no restrictions.

Comment: Thanks . If one of you can post it as an answer, I'll accept it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a matter of convention. Indeed with the other axioms, the following would all be equivalent:

1. $\mathcal{A}$ is non-empty.
2. $\varnothing\in\mathcal{A}$.
3. $\Omega\in\mathcal{A}$.

Different authors choose different conventions for these, and usually this equivalence is one of the first things you prove.